# How do I get VB6 to integrate with Visual Source Safe 6.0?

Tags: version-control, vb6, visual-sourcesafe

We use Visual Source Safe 6.0 at work and VB6 is supposed to integrate smoothly with Source Safe.  Both applications are installed on my PC, but VB6 is not showing the options to integrate with Source Safe (e.g. checking out a file, seeing if a file is shared, etc.).

What do I need to do to get VB6 to integrate with Source Safe 6.0?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check the file `C:\WINDOWS\VBADDIN.INI` and make sure that there is a line "vbscc=1" under the "[Add-Ins32]" section of the file. Re-start VB6 and go to "Add-Ins | Add-In Manager". The "Source Code Control" add-in should be listed.

Updated with correction from Mark Hurd.

Comment: "siva" and "avi" say this works for them. They posted this information as answers, but it should be a comment really. So I am obliging!

Comment: For completeness, I found it was `C:\WINDOWS\vbaddin.ini`. NB no final `s`.

Comment: All the guides out there regarding integration of VB6 & Source Control (SourceSafe,TFS) mention to add the line "VBSCC=3" or 1...but unless it is placed UNDER the section [Add-Ins32] or this section is not existant ([Add-Ins32]) IT DOESN'T WORK

Answer (score 2):

What version of Windows are you running? If you're running a version that uses User Account Control (Vista, 7, 2008 Server), there have been reports of UAC causing the SourceSafe options to disappear from VB6. Disable on the machine and see if that corrects it.

(I hate advocating disabling UAC; it's always a weapon of last resort for me, but if it works, it works.)

Comment: I'm using Windows XP SP2, so I guess it's not the UAC.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the source control add-in isn't loaded?

- In the VB6 IDE, go to the Add-Ins->Add-In Manager... menu
- In the "Available Add-Ins" column look for "Source Code Control" and select it
- In the frame in the lower right labeled "Load Behavior", check the options "Loaded/Unloaded" and "Load on Startup"
- Click OK

Comment: hmmm...I don't see "source code control" as an add-in.  Also, I don't see the ability to install a new add-in.

Comment: @Ben: Then I would try reinstalling VSS and see if the SCC add-in appears in the list.  You have to have it for the integration to work.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a *long* time, but I think you have to install vb (visual studio) first, and source safe after.

Comment: I'm hoping there's something I can do so I don't have to re-install any applications. But thanks for the suggestion.