# Configuring VB6 with VSS 2005

Tags: version-control, vb6, visual-sourcesafe-2005

I have configured VB6 with VSS 2005, following functionality working fine :

1. Check In and Check Out of code
2. Get Latest Version
3. Showing error when code Check Out by another user.
4. Showing error if use try to edit code without Check In ( only when user takes latest version)

Difference I am finding in VB.Net and VB6 configuration with VSS are :

1. Code not getting Check In automatically when user try to edit code, without Check In Code.
2. Not allowing user to save changes and Check In code later after 1 or 2 days. User require Check In code before closing code.
3. Showing "Path/File access error:" for .vbp file.When user tries to save code on machine.
4. Allowing user to edit code without Check in when user opens the code first time.

I did all the settings mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421291/how-do-i-get-vb6-to-integrate-with-visual-source-safe-6-0) link.

Comment: Please - PLEASE - lose VSS and get a *real* version control system.  OK?

Comment: Thanks paulsm4 but using VSS is my company's decision.So,its mandatory for me to use it.

Comment: Difference number 4: VB6 always insists on saving the VBP file, even if you have not actually changed it in any way.

Answer (score 0):

As MarkJ mentioned the vbp file is always saved when the application runs. You can cancel out of the dialog to run the project anyway but this is more hassle than just right clicking on the project root and checking out.

I am using Team Foundation Server with my VB6 projects and there is no auto check out in this either. I'm afraid you will have to live with it until you port the code the .NET

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/Workaround.aspx?FeedbackID=196185)<sub>dead link: [WayBack version](http://web.archive.org/web/20100327000853/http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/196185/vss-2005-add-in-for-vb6-does-not-display-glyphs-unless-all-files-in-the-project-are-in-vss)</sub> there is also a problem when you have some files or documents not in SourceSafe.

Specifically (as I still document [here](http://www.ozemail.com.au/~markhurd/)), when some of the files of a project are not associated with SourceSafe often no files have their SourceSafe status glyphs displayed.

The workaround I found was displaying the Add Files dialogue and then cancelling it. I offer [my public domain add-in](http://www.ozemail.com.au/~markhurd/VssFixAddIn.zip) that automatically implements this workaround.

And BTW, make sure you install the latest VSS Service Pack.